# ActivityMonitor getHits() doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I tried this test but getHits() always return 0. Anyone can help me?

```
 public void testSettingsAboutShazamClickOnLink() {

    Instrumentation inst = getInstrumentation();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intentFilter.addDataScheme("mailto");


    ActivityMonitor monitor = inst.addMonitor(intentFilter, null, false);
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


    assertEquals(0, monitor.getHits());
    inst.getContext().startActivity(emailIntent);        
    monitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(5000);
    assertEquals(1, monitor.getHits());
    inst.removeMonitor(monitor);
 }
```

Comment: The goal is to recall another program in this case gmail to send an email, so there is no real activity to call, I start the intent with inst.getContext().startActivity(emailIntent); The test works fine and a new email is open to be written but getHits() return always 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem. I used Solo of Robotium and apparently Solo inserts an ActivityMonitor that matches every Filter, so when you call startActivity, it calls execStartActivity in the Instrumentation class, whose code is

```
 Context who, IBinder contextThread, IBinder token, Activity target,
    Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    IApplicationThread whoThread = (IApplicationThread) contextThread;
    if (mActivityMonitors != null) {
        synchronized (mSync) {
            final int N = mActivityMonitors.size();
            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                final ActivityMonitor am = mActivityMonitors.get(i);
               if (am.match(who, null, intent)) {
                   am.mHits++;
                    if (am.isBlocking()) {
                        return requestCode >= 0 ? am.getResult() : null;
                    }
                   break;
                }
            }
       }
    }
```

As soon as there is an ActivityMonitor that matches something the mHits of that monitor is increased end the "cycle for" breaks. Given that calling Solo was the first thing I did, the first ActivityMonitor to check is the one of Solo, given that this matches everything, any other ActivityMonitors added after it is not checked, so no mHits variable is increased for the other monitors. If you want to understand more see the execStartMonitor method of Instrumentation class, remembering that this method is called after startActivity is called.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/app/Instrumentation.java#Instrumentation.execStartActivity%28android.content.Context%2Candroid.os.IBinder%2Candroid.os.IBinder%2Candroid.app.Activity%2Candroid.content.Intent%2Cint%29

Comment: So what is the answer?