# Android - ActivityMonitor getHits() always return zero

Tags: android, instrumentation, activity-monitor

Here is the testing code:

```
    Instrumentation inst = getInstrumentation();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intentFilter.addDataScheme("http://");
    intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    ActivityMonitor monitor = inst.addMonitor(intentFilter, null, false);
    assertEquals(0, monitor.getHits());

    homeViewController.onItemClick(null, null, 5, 0);
    monitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(5000);
    assertEquals(1, monitor.getHits());
    inst.removeMonitor(monitor);
```

and here's the tested code:

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sendIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.my_website)));
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

getHits() always returns zero. I am not using any third libraries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566967/activitymonitor-gethits-doesnt-work is this duplicate ?

Comment: If you checked the answer over there, you will find that the reason is the usage of Solo of Robotium. "I am not using any third libraries".

Comment: A bounty couldn't help too?!

Comment: Can you please post your xml where you declare the intent filter. I may be jumping ahead of myself but does the intent filter expect a host and path prefix as well?

Comment: I didn't create any intent filters in XML. The intent filter in the code is just for "unit testing" the code.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been around for some time, but wanted to provide a solution that worked for me.

intentFilter.addDataScheme("http://") is wrong and should be changed to intentFilter.addDataScheme("http") and you should be good.